# SQL counting rows by grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table:

```
A       B
 ---------
1       Date1
1       Date1
1       Date1
1       Date2
2       Date1
3       Date3
4       Date2
4       Date1
1       Date3

SELECT A, count(A) FROM `table` WHERE B BETWEEN 'Date1' AND 'Date2'
GROUP BY A
ORDER BY A
```

When I do normal query:

```
A       B
----------
1        1
1        1
1        1
2        1
3        1
4        1
4        1
```

Need to count no of days?  is there any simple queries for this? please help

Need data like:

```
A       B
----------
1        3
2        1
3        1
4        2
```

Comment: Where is the "Date" column coming from in `GROUP BY DATE(Date)`?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. what do you want to get as output? and what is created_At column and date column

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Before exerting any effort, always check with us first.

Comment: The table you show has two columns: A (int) and B (date). The query however selects three other columns from `table` : A (int), created_at (date), and Date (date)? Could you please clarify?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I edited, have a look now

Comment: There is still `GROUP BY DATE(Date)`. What is `Date` and why do you use the function `DATE` on it?

Comment: I have edited again, please have a look

Comment: For A = 1 I see **four** dates (Date1, Date1, Date1 and Date2), i.e. **two** different dates, `BETWEEN 'Date1' AND 'Date2'`. Your result, however, shall not count two and not four, but **three**. How do you get this 3?

Comment: And you are saying that you group by A, but get three result records for A = 1??? That seems impossible. Is A a string containing '1', '1 ' and '1  ' maybe?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
SELECT T1.id as id, COUNT(COALESCE(T2.totalcountdepartmentuserwise, 0)) AS totalcountdepartmentuserwise 
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT id FROM users WHERE company_id = 33
     ) AS T1 
     LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT user_id, COUNT(distinct user_id) AS totalcountdepartmentuserwise FROM userlogs WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-25' GROUP BY user_id, DATE(created_at) ORDER BY user_id
     ) AS T2 ON T2.user_id = t1.id GROUP BY id
```

Comment: This "answer" has nothing to do with your question. Suddenly two tables are involved? And the query and/or the table design doesn't even make much sense. A column called ID you need to apply DISTINCT on? Why?A count on coalesce(...,0)? What the heck? A distinct count of user IDs within a group containing the user ID? What is that supposed to do? This is definitely a bad query and I would not recommend keeping it.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you need count(distinct B)

```
SELECT A, count(distinct B) 
FROM `table` WHERE B BETWEEN 'Date1' AND 'Date2'
GROUP BY A 
ORDER BY A;
```

Comment: I have edited, please have look

Comment: I have update the answer ..

Comment: it gives same value.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. As in the question, table and query don't match (different columns). The result you are showing is definetely not grouped by A. `COUNT(B)` is the same as `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: I have update the asnwer..